# C# DotNet.Highcharts Column datalabel percentage

Tags: c#, .net, highcharts

Would somebody kindly explain to me why this does not work. I want to display both the value and the percentage on top of the column but, using the below returns NaN for the percentage value.

Below is the data returned.

```
    xAxis: { categories: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] }, 
    series: [{ data: [1, 4, 3, 7, 10, 1], name: 'Value' }]

.SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Column = new PlotOptionsColumn
                {
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsColumnDataLabels
                    {
                        Enabled = true,
                        Formatter = "function() { var dataSum = 0; for (var i = 0; i < this.series.data.length; i++) { dataSum += this.series.data[i] }; var pcnt = (this.y / dataSum) * 100; return '<b>Value</b>: ' + this.point.y + '<br/>' + '<b>Percent</b>: ' + pcnt + '%'; }"
                    }
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this part of your code:

```
dataSum += this.series.data[i]
```

Right now you are trying to sum points.. but I'm pretty sure you want to sum points' y-values:

```
dataSum += this.series.data[i].y
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ywr3L/41/

**Extra note:**

You will get long numbers, try to display `pcnt.toFixed(2)` instead of `pcnt` in function's return.

Comment: DING DING DING, we have a winner! Thank you very much, my head can now rest!

Answer (score 2):

I think `dataSum` is still 0.

`this.series.data.length` and `this.series.data[i]` are undefined. Use `this.series[0].data.length` and `this.series[0].data[i]` instead.

Comment: Tried with the amendments but no luck. Jsfiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/egc30uao/1/